# Client hits 80072EE2 error while downloading update from WSUS server

Tags: windows, wsus

So, the WSUS server is configured to download latest updates from Microsoft and then the other servers would download the update from the WSUS server.

There's no issue for the WSUS server to download updates from Microsoft.

Local servers and computers are able to get the notification of new update, but then the problem occur when they're trying to download from WSUS.

For example, the file server would get notified of 1 new update (100KB) and it starts the download. But then, the download progress would stay at 0% until windows update pops up the error message.

Any idea?

I've done some research on the internet, most of them are about the issue of getting update from Microsoft instead of Local WSUS.

Comment: probably obvious, but don't forget to check the proxy settings in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out our network guy did a mistake in configuring the WSUS server. Which ends up our WSUS not downloading any of the update packages from Microsoft.

Therefore, although it is reported there are new updates available, yet the client servers are unable to find and download the update from our WSUS server.

Making sure the WSUS server to properly download and keep the update package solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

i had this problem but now it has been solved.there is some setting that you have to check.

1. windows firewall,it should allow connections for private network and domain
2. you should configure automatic update in group policy ( without enabling this option updating with wsus will not work)
3. in IIS expand wsus website and select selfupdate and enable directory browsing and do the same job for clientwebservice
4. in client pc open cmd and type " gpupdate /force " and check for updates

note:  in group policy dont forget to set port for specify intranet microsoft update service location like  `"http://servername:8530"`  the default port for wsus is 8530

[check this out for more detail information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852346.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The error is

```
0x80072EE2 ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT
```

It's a network timeout error.  Most likely, something is preventing network communications.

[Windows Firewall?  Hardware firewalls?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693717.aspx)  Is the address of the WSUS server typed correctly in the registries of the client computers?  How's DNS? Can clients resolve the WSUS URL correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, WSUS application pool was shutting down in middle of talking to client (therefore 0x80072EE2 = timeout error) because it had limits on it's memory use. Go to IIS manager on WSUS server, Application Pools, WsusPool, right click on it, Recycling, and remove limit on Private memory usage.

I also recommend to create 8 Wsus application pools (WsusPool1, WsusPool2,..etc. from WsusPool template) and move each of 8 applications to it's separate pool, to better optimize IIS.

In my opinion, WSUS server with WID on it and >10000 updates should have at least 4 GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I had this `80072EE2` issue on three of our 2012R2 servers. A call to Microsoft support helped us fix all of them.

1. Check all the required services (see list below) are running. I found some of these services needed regular checking to ensure they were still running (after I had started them minutes before).
2. Check there's enough disk space free.  It's probably more than you think.  For my 6GB of download, the Microsoft engineer recommended 33GB free disk space.  Not sure how he did the maths.
3. Check there are no policies in place which would prevent Windows Update from running.  To do that, type `rsop.msc` at an (elevated?) command prompt, look under "Administrative templates" for "Windows Update".  The absence of an entry means there's no policy preventing Windows Update.
4. Click the "Check online for updates from Windows Update" link, rather than the "Check for updates" link.
   [image: Windows Update screenshot showing which link to use to check for updates]

Required services are:

- App Readiness
- Backgroung intelligence Transfer Services
- Cryptographic services
- Windows update
- Windows Module Installer
- Windows installer